# Reapply a position in a company

Tags: resume, new-job

Ten years ago I left a company that I had worked for over 7 years.  Last year I rejoined the company but resigned during my probation period due to family issues. Now I see another opportunity at the same company and very much like the scope of responsibility and wish to apply.  In their, online application they required to fill out the last position that I held at the company.  Do I state the one that I left last year? Or I can skip that and say my last position was the position 10 years ago?

Comment: I would list both. If the form doesn't allow you to do that, list the last one, and use the cover letter to expand on the fact that you worked at that company 7+ years and that you know the company inside out. Either way, HR should have both recorded under your name, so it's not something you should fret too much over.

Answer (score 1):

No, the last position is *the last position* you held, irrespective of the duration.

Mention the last position you had, and if asked, be ready to explain why you left the last time. You can however, use the cover letter to explain that the last stint with the organization was rather brief, due to personal reasons and add a bit about the previous position which was a much longer association.